# How to check if word is in alphabetical order

Tags: bash

I 'd like to find a bash only (no sed, awk, perl, ...) for finding out if a word is in alphabetical order, in other words every letter is.
example: 
bdjkz is true, 
ahjmno is true, 
sdgla is false.

I'm already struggling just comparing ascii values for characters, so if anyone could point me in the right direction for that it would help a lot!

Thanks

Comment: Please post your current attempts.

Comment: I've got nothing, i don't know how to compare characters to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Pure bash solution (no external tool used), using Parameter Expansion to address characters inside strings:

```
function compare () {
    word=$1
    for (( pos=0; pos<${#word}-1; pos++ )) ; do
        [[ ${word:pos:1} < ${word:pos+1:1} ]] || return 1
    done
    return 0
}
```

Tested with

```
for word in bdjkz ahjmno sdgla ; do
    if compare $word ; then
        echo $word ordered
    else
        echo $word not ordered
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can utilize other command line tools (but not `awk`, `sed`, `perl`), you can try:

```
[[ "YOURSTRING" = "$(echo "YOURSTRING" | grep -o '.' | sort -n |tr -d '\n')" ]] && \
  echo "Alphabetic order"
```

1. `[[ ... ]]` is testing the expresion
2. `"YOURSTRING" =` string comparison
3. `"$( ... )"` capture the inner workings output in a string
4. `echo "YOURSTRING" | grep -o '.'` print every character on a line from `"YOURSTRING"` (`-o '.'`: print only the matches for any single character - ***NOTE***: you might need a new version of `grep` for this option)
5. ... `sort -n |` sort the output from 4.
6. ... `tr -d '\n'` rejoin the characters from 5. (by deleting the trailing new line characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
p='bdjkz'
q=$(fold -w1 <<< "$p"|sort|tr -d "\n")
[[ "$p" == "$q" ]] && echo "in alphabetical order" || echo "not in alphabetical order"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s=($(echo "existingString" | grep -o .))  # put each character of input string in an array.

k=($(printf '%s\n' "${s[@]}" | sort))  # sorts the input string

if [[ "${s[*]}" == "${k[*]}"  ]]; then  # comparing the input string array with sorted array 
echo "alphabetical" 
else 
echo "not alphabetical"
fi
```

Comment: Try to explain *why* your sulution will solve the problem, otherwise your posts end up in the Low Quality Review. See [answer]

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk  Comments added, please check if they satisfactorily explains the answer.

Comment: @brasofilo Comments added, please check if they satisfactorily explains the answer

Comment: I think the filter for Low Quality checks if the answer is "code-only".

Comment: ok, I shall keep in mind, I thought code is self explanatory, anyways I shud had put some explanation